# My server is being hammered by TCP connections

Tags: apache-2.2

I've recently transferred my site to a VPS since then the server has gone down regularly due to it being "hammered" by connection made to it. I have blocked many IP addresses but it seems this would be a endless task. I'm new to servers can anyone please help me or point me to a tutorial on how to protect my server from this attack and offer advice on what to do?

It's running Apache

Thank you

Comment: Define "hammered"?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you could be the target of a DDOS attack, I have seen this happen several times when people go to a host and are assigned an IP address previously used by a high target site. (Or an honest highly popular site - may have an auto update type program that hasn't forwarded on to their new site etc.)

You can obviously use a firewall, but being realistic, Any sort of prevention would probably be costly or out of your control (e.g. setting null routes). You are much better off getting in contact with the host and simply asking for a new IP or to help in this matter.